# Reverse for 'password_reset_done' not found. 'password_reset_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with django's view "password_reset_done".
When I try to open **accounts/reset-password** I have this error. 
But if I open url **accounts/reset-password/done** it works.

URLS.PY of "accounts" app

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login , logout, password_reset, 
    password_reset_done
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^profile/prpage/(\d+)/$', views.profile, name='prpage'),
    url(r'^profile-edit/$', views.profiledit, name='profile-edit'),
    url(r'^login/$', login ,{'template_name':'accounts/login.html'}, 
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    url(r'^profile/(?P<proj_id>\d+)/$', views.userprojectpage, 
        name='userprojectpage'),
    url(r'^changepassword/$', views.changepassword, name='changepassword'),
    url(r'^reset-password/$', password_reset, name='reset_password'),
    url(r'^reset-password/done/$', password_reset_done, 
        name='password_reset_done'),
]
```

please help! Thanks in advance)

Comment: "When I try to open accounts/reset-password I have this error. But if I open url accounts/reset-password/done it works.

" . Is it the other way around?

Comment: Do you have a namespace for app accounts ?

Comment: yes. I have a namespace = "accounts" for accounts app

Comment: Then you have to call 'accounts:password_reset_done'. Check whether you have accounts in the url call.

Comment: You mean in my template? But I have no template connected with reset-password yet, bacause I thought "accounts/reset-password" must open default page of django's reset passord.

Comment: In that case, you should include the auth urls in the urls file. No need to have them in the accounts urls.py.

Comment: Thank you. it works

Comment: Hi @beka what version of django you using please? I have the same problem I fixed mine, I hope be able to help you with this problem.

Comment: Hi @DilMac Im using django version 1.11

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal Tried both ways and worked great!

Comment: I managed to recreate this error while i tried to reset the password of an account that didn't had a password specified. Specify the password of the User object and it could work

Answer (score 10):

Add *success_url* parameter of Class Based View [PasswordResetView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView). This will replace default route of password_reset_done

```
from django.urls import path, re_path, include, reverse_lazy

path('reset/',PasswordResetView.as_view(

        template_name='password_reset.html',
        email_template_name='password_reset_email.html',
        subject_template_name='password_reset_subject.txt',
        ...
    
        success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_done')

        ...
        ... 
        ),name='password_reset'),
```

Comment: `from django.urls import path, re_path, include, reverse_lazy`

Comment: This answer fixed my error. I was using django==3.x.x

Comment: @ArifulHaque I am happy if it can help you. Please vote this answer if this useful

Comment: @koderstory I already voted for this

Answer (score 2):

11 there are some change made look like  password_reset, password_reset_done not able to import therefore display this error regarding this url https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/contrib/auth/views.py.

There are two way to resolve the error above.

1. to resolve this error add url(r'',  include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), to main urls.py in your project. This will stopped the error and keep your urls in your accounts:
   url(r'^reset-password/$', password_reset, name='reset_password'),
   url(r'^reset-password/done/$', password_reset_done, 
       name='password_reset_done'),
   I have resolved this error like above and it works fine.
2. Second way to resolve the error is different than first option above,remove the  url(r'',  include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), from main urls.py file and in your accounts/urls.py add following url's:
   url(r'^reset-password/$', password_reset, 
       {'template_name':'reset_password.html', 
        'post_reset_redirect':'accounts:password_reset_done', 
        'email_template_name': 'reset_password_email.html'}, 
        name='reset_password'),

   url(r'^reset-password/done/$', password_reset_done,
       {'template_name': 'reset_password_done.html'}, name='password_reset_done'),

   url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P.+)/$', 
       password_reset_confirm, {'template_name': 'reset_password_confirm.html',
       'post_reset_redirect':'accounts:password_reset_complete'}, 
       name='password_reset_confirm'),

This is the second solution and working.

I hope that helps your problem and sorry for delay respond your last comment, I was away.

DilMac